# ошибка при создании триггера mysql

Tags: mysql, триггер

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Delivery` AFTER INSERT ON `pending`
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SET @index = NEW.`index`;
  SET @sms_count = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `pending` WHERE `index` = @index);
  INSERT INTO `delivery` SET
    `index` = @index, `countSMS` = @sms_count
  WHERE `index` = @index;
END
```

что я делаю не так?

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

Answer (score 1):

1. Не используйте в триггере пользовательские переменные (`@index`, `@sms_count`).
2. Оператор `INSERT INTO` не допускает кляузы `WHERE`.

Comment: я пробую все варианты, просто никак не могу найти решение своей, как мне раньше казалось, просто задачи. нужно средствами Mysql организовать создание таблицы с общей информацией о рассылке. при создании рассылки добавляется в таблицу n-ое кол-во номеров, с разным временем отправления. так вот нужно в другую таблицу вывести ('индекс','номер','кол-во смс','время начала','время завершения') время начала = время отправки первой смс, время завершения = время отправки последней смс, кол-во смс = количеству записей с определенным индексом.

Answer (score 0):

А так будет работать?

```
CREATE TRIGGER `Delivery` AFTER INSERT ON `pending`
 FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO `delivery` (
    `index`, `countSMS`
  ) SELECT
    NEW.`index`, COUNT(*)
  FROM `pending`
  WHERE `index` = NEW.`index`;
END
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50471/discussion-on-answer-by-anton-shchyrov-----mysql).